# Using selenium to click on a text link

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am able to click on the link using selenium but it opens a new tab for me ,instead of opening in the same tab , and it just shows data; in the address bar and not content in the page.

public class InternetExplorerDriverTest {

```
 public static void clickLinkByHref(String href) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    List<WebElement> anchors = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    Iterator<WebElement> i = anchors.iterator();

    while(i.hasNext()) {
        WebElement anchor = i.next();
     if(anchor.getAttribute("href").contains(href)) {

         anchor.click();
         break;
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("https://url");
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement element =       

driver.findElement(By.id("323bb07bc611227a018aea9eb8f3b35e"));
 element.click();

 clickLinkByHref("ea7d96126f92a100f3ae60526e3ee4e0");
```

}

}

The console in the eclipse shows below 'after 2 minutes'

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 61.87 seconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'NLLR4000290859', ip: '10.29.137.219', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startSession(ChromeDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
    at InternetExplorerDriverTest.clickLinkByHref(InternetExplorerDriverTest.java:41)
    at InternetExplorerDriverTest.main(InternetExplorerDriverTest.java:94)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("gsft_main")));
```

The above code line was required to switch to the iframe . This works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try reviewing this example: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

Also, is it possible that your link targets *_blank* ?

Here's a simple example that works:

package org.mitre.tests;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Wtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "exe\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            WebElement text_link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Learn HTML"));
            text_link.click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.quit();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("done.");
    } //end main()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am rephrasing my question : The previous issue was because I am initializing the chromedriver again.
So this time I am passing the driver object to the method.

Now I observe that the link that I am trying to click is not being recognized at all.
Developer tools in chrome shows me the link as in structure below:

```
 <main 
     <div
      <ifreame
        #document
          <html
            <body
              <form
                 <div
                     ::before
                   <a href=wizard_view.do?sys_action=sysverb_wizard_ans&WIZARD:action=follow&wiz_referring_url=&wiz_collection_key=&wiz_collectionID=&wiz_collection=&wiz_collection_related_field=&wiz_view=&wiz_action=sysverb_new&sys_id=ea7d96126f92a100f3ae60526e3ee4e0&sysparm_query=active=true&sysparm_target=&sys_target=change_ddfdff>Standard (from Template)

</a>
::after
</div>
....
```

How do I identify and click this particular text link?I tried css selector,xpath etc but didn't work

```
anchors = dd.findElements(By.linkText(Standard (from Template)));      

anchors2 =     dd.findElements(By.cssSelector(a[href*='ea7d96126f92a100f3ae60526e3ee4e0'] )));
```

Also there are a 10 div sections with same class name each of which is a text link. I want to click on of them (see above)